# Find and replace multiple values without recurring substitution

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table where first column is the text to search for and the second the text to replace. See an example below.

[image: Replace Table]

The first column has only single character.
The key here is the text "b" appears in the search and replace column. But i only want a character to change once. But I want a character to be replaced only once and not replace a replaced character.

See below an example of the text and desired output.

[image: Desired Output]

I have tried using the LAMBDA and VBA Solution provided by ablebits.com. [Click Here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-find-replace-multiple-values/)

But in all cases, the text "a" that gets replaced to "b" which gets replaced again to "oo". So the final output becomes "oooodr" instead of "booddr".

Please note that my original replace table is quite large so nested substitute formula is not practical. Any guidance/help is highly appreciated.

PS: Here is a sample of original replace table which has several latin characters also. Please consider this while offering a solution.

[image: Original Replace table]

Comment: So control the order in which things are replaced. First do the replacement of "b". Then do "a"...

Comment: Why isn't the desired output `booddr`?

Comment: Correct. It should be booddr. Apologies

Comment: @SolarMike: This is only an example. There are several other instances where this occurs.

Comment: is the text to replace always only 1 character? and if not what about overlaps (for example: `hello`, and `lost` overlap the `lo` so if both were a text to replace you'd have to have a way to prioritize (since `lo` would be part of 2 texts to replace) - if text to replace only ever is a single character this is a non issue

Comment: Yes. Text to replace is only a single character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you can just lookup and combine, rather than perform multiple substitutions. Assuming your lookup table is in `E2:F4` (excluding headers):

```
=LET(
    ε,A1,
    ξ,E2:F4,
    ζ,MID(ε,SEQUENCE(LEN(ε)),1),
    CONCAT(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ζ,ξ,2,0),ζ))
)
```

Comment: Worked in this case. But my replace table has several latin/special characters. I will include this in the question.

Comment: Why would this matter? Can you clarify with an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through the string itself, check if the character needs to be replaced, if so add the replacement to the new string, if not add the character itself to the new string. And at the End of the loop you'll have the desired String.

```
Function getReplacedString(myString As String) As String
    Dim resultString As String
    Dim character As String
    Dim replaceRange As Range
    Dim cellWithValue As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set replaceRange = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:B2")
    
    For i = 1 To Len(myString)
        character = Mid(myString, i, 1)
        Set cellWithValue = replaceRange.Find(character)
        If Not cellWithValue Is Nothing Then
            Set cellWithValue = cellWithValue.Offset(, 1)
            resultString = resultString & cellWithValue.Value
        Else
            resultString = resultString & character
        End If
    Next i
    getReplacedString = resultString
End Function
```